# which SharePoint Version should be used on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am wondering if I use Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise. Then which SharePoint version should I used? I tried SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise SP1, but failed (error message, not compatible with OS).

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Did you get the 64 bit version of SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, I am using 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B7816D90-5FC6-4347-89B0-A80DEB27A082&displaylang=en) to run on  Windows Server 2008 R2.
Then you will need to [slipstream SP2](http://blogs.msdn.com/opal/archive/2009/05/08/install-moss-2007-wss-3-0-on-windows-server-2008-r2-you-will-need-sp2-slipstream.aspx) for the install.